# how to add checkbox control in DevExpress XtraTree List

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

Hai,
  Am using DevExpress Tree List in C#.NET application .I want to add  checkbox control in DevExpress XtraTree List.Please help

Thank you.

Comment: My advice for help would be to search the [DevExpress support centre](http://beta.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx#cD1UNHxQMXw1OHNlYXJjaHRleHQ9Y2hlY2tib3g=) itself. It is a really good resource and you can post a new question there too. It might be a better place to ask than here in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the column's ColumnEdit property to an instance of the RepositoryItemCheckEdit class.  For more details, please refer to

- http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5632
- http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5633